# Stagged validation/parsing in Amazon Lex

Tags: python, amazon-lex

I want to make a simple quote bot which needs to know about addresses and dimensions. Currently I have hacked one together with a python state machine and rasa NLU for the intent stuff, though the nature of the data means most of the entities are better extracted by hand.

For example, an opening sentence might be "i want to send 4 boxes from A postcodeA to B postcodeB they're 3 by 3 by 3m each". These addresses need to be validated, which may involve a back and forth (did you mean this postcode, or maybe that state? This isn't a valid match, please choose from this list, etc...).

Additionally, the order of the validation might be weird. For example, one could have a suburb, postcode, and is_valid slot. There are several possibilities: they could enter a valid S + P, just S, an invalid S alone, a valid S and P which are individually valid but not a match, etc. In some cases I want to defer validation to make use of other information, for example if an invalid suburb was given but a valid postcode, i would use the postcode to inform suggestions for the correct suburb. However, if an invalid suburb was given but no postcode, there is no point asking for a postcode because i would want to get a valid suburb first. In this way having a slot ordering of 'suburb', 'postcode', 'is_valid' doesn't quite cut it as far as i can tell.

I suppose the validation call for suburb and postcode can just have their own set of switch statements which look at the other slots which may have been filled at the same time? Seems a bit chicken and egg, as would need to wait for validation of those as well, and may end up requiring calling Lambda's from within Lambda's. For example, if the validation fails, the bot asks for more info, but the validation of *that* info may require a *different* process/lambda than the original input

It could also be they don't include any details about the object, in which case it needs to be prompted for later after the address stuff is all sorted out. For example, if they fail to include info about dimensions i want to ask 'what're the dimensions' and allow them to either include just measurements or weights and quantities as well - this i understand as standard slot filling.

So my question is: how difficult/reasonable is it to have validation calls in Lambdas actually lead to side-paths in the conversation? Previously i had done something like this in a slot-filling setting by having 'is_valid' slots all over the place (especially if I don't want to simply throw an 'isn't valid' error and robotically re-ask the original question'). Is there a better way?

Also, how would one manage 'interrupt' intents? That is, a set of intents which would trigger 'do you want to go restart?' kind of questions, which will return to the original state if the user replies 'no', and, ideally, if they say yes can return to a specific point in the conversation (which i imagine would be achieved by just resetting appropriate slots to empty)

Also, not wedded to the idea of Amazon Lex, any of the pre-canned cases which reduce amount of boiler plate code are good too.

Apologies for word vomit.

Comment: You'll have more success with help on StackOverflow if you narrow down your questions and separate them out into smaller individual questions. It will also be more useful to others who are searching for one of the same specific questions you ask but can't find it inside of a list of questions. Word vomit apologies accepted though haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, ok here's what I can offer:

### 1. Validation Difficulty

> how difficult/reasonable is it to have validation calls in Lambdas actually lead to side-paths in the conversation?

Building a complex validation and conversation algorithm is standard practice for Lex Developers of service bots. So it is very reasonable to expect to have to do that yourself either in Lambda, or somewhere else and just use Lambda as a go-between. So the difficulty lies in your hands, and maybe you can find APIs that you can use to validate addresses and postal codes like Google Maps to make that part easier.

### 2. 'is_valid' Slots

> Previously i had done something like this in a slot-filling setting by having 'is_valid' slots all over the place (especially if I don't want to simply throw an 'isn't valid' error and robotically re-ask the original question'). Is there a better way?

Lex does have a better way: `sessionAttributes`! A good practice is to only create slots for holding the values you need to fulfill each intent. For **anything** else, you can happily rely on `sessionAttributes` to keep track of the conversation path, slot validity, slot history, intent history, interruption intents, etc, etc, etc, as much as you can imagine. It's completely up to you how to organize your bot logic and keep track of current and past states of the convo there.

For example: You could have slot: `postalCodeA`
And in `sessionAttributes` also have: `postalCodeA_valid`, `postalCodeA_confirmed`, `postalCodeA_attempts` etc.

And use those `sessionAttributes` values to determine the conversation path in your logic. When you find a slot is invalid, you could save that value in an `..._attempts` or `..._history` list in `sessionAttributes`, then set `..._valid` to `false`, and reset the slot to `null`, and re-elicit that slot with a message explaining why it was invalid, or try to elicit an address slot instead of a postal code slot.

### 3. Interrupt Intents

> Also, how would one manage 'interrupt' intents? That is, a set of intents which would trigger 'do you want to go restart?' kind of questions

As I hinted at earlier, the answer to this is also `sessionAttributes`! When your user is inside of one intent (intentA), Lex will first attempt to fill the current elicit slot with their input, but if it doesn't match, Lex will also check if the input matches a different intent's utterances. So you could have an interrupt intent (intentB) with utterances like "let's start over", "nevermind", "back up", etc. Then in all of your normal intents, you keep a backup of that intent's slot values in `sessionAttribtues`, as well as something like `last_intent` to know where a user was previously in case it changes.

This would allow you to handle interrupt intents like this:

1. user enters intentA
2. intentA fills some slots, and backs them up in `sessionAttributes`
3. user says "lets start over" triggering intentB
4. intentB asks for confirmation of canceling intentA

(Yes) intentB fulfills the intent after erasing intentA values from `sessionAttributes` and returns user to start with `elicitIntent` and asks "how else may I help you?"

(No) intentB passes the user back to intentA (which you know because you kept track of `sessionAttributes.last_intent`) and send a confirmation of continuing with intentA with `confirmIntent`: "Alright, I still remember where we left off, would you like to continue {intentA action}?" (the response will be sent to intentA, where you can handle  that).

5. (if user wants to continue with intentA) intentA fills the new empty slots from `sessionAttributes` and uses other `sessionAttributes` values to continue through your algorithm to the point where it left off, delivering the same elicit slot that it was last on, and the user is impressed with your bot's intelligence. =)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the comprehensive and helpful reply! I will investigate session variables properly. I have a couple of followup questions but i see i am character restricted here - would you mind fielding them through PM or other avenue? I will happily post their resolution here/wherever appropriate

Comment: @zylatis if your questions are to clarify something in my answer, then go ahead and ask here. But if your questions deal with how do you take the next steps in implementing my suggestions, then create whole new questions, and separate them out. It's better for everyone that way.